# Video converters don't work anymore after reinstalling Windows

Tags: windows-7, video-conversion, handbrake

A few days ago, I decided to reinstall Windows 7 as my HD partition seemed to be nearly full and things were slowing down. I'd been using Handbrake almost exclusively to convert TV recordings and used Freemake on occasion.

Following the reinstall, I can't get either to work:

- Handbrake says it's encoding for about 2 seconds and then says it's finished, but there are no converted files of any size.
- Freemake just says 'Conversion Error' and won't go any further.

As an experiment I tried two programs that I don't normally use, VideoReDo & Any Video Converter. Both worked fine.

Anyone got any clues?

Comment: Try and install a codec pack such as K-Lite and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when i updated my VLC to 2.0 and it didn't include the libdvdcss which Handbrake uses to convert DVD videos..this helped me [Webluke](http://www.webluke.net/2011/08/handbrake-windows-7-64-bit-dvd-ripping/)